# Change return value of the method with attribute

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I want to have a class like this (pseudocode):

```
public MyClass
{
   private bool isValid;

   [CheckValid]
   public int DoSomething()
   {
      return 1;
   }
}
```

Now, I want my `[CheckValid]` attribute to check `isValid` property, and if it is true, then allow `DoSomething()` to execute, or, if it is false, make `DoSomething()` return `default(int)` (or at least make the code inside `DoSomething()` inaccesible)

Comment: Attributes are only evaluated when they are examined (i.e. through reflection), so I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Have you looked in to policy injection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a feature of C#: attributes are not *executed* as such. There are, however, extension frameworks like [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) that *would* allow this - basically it rewrites the code at the IL level to inject functionality, typically based on attributes. But that requires additional tooling.

In C# "out of the box", your best bet would be:

```
public int DoSomething() {
    CheckValid(); // might throw an exception
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Then how does the standard built-in `[Authorize]` attribute works? I want the same functionality, but with my own code.

Comment: @ojek those work because the framework in which they apply (MVC, etc) **explicitly checks** for such attributes via reflection, and invokes their code directly. That doesn't happen as a language feature.

Comment: @ojek as a human example: if I write "do not open" on a sticky label, and adhere that label to a box: that does not stop anyone opening the box. It is only useful if some goes out of their way to *look for the label*, read what it says, and *follow* what it says. In the case of frameworks like MVC - it is the framework that does all this checking before electing to perform actions on your behalf.